# Button is hidden only in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app,I am playing video using MPMoviePlayer.
I am adding a **"Skip Ad"** (you can see that on the right side of movie player)button on Movie Player.It works fine in iOS5, but when I run my app in iOS6, the button is hidden when Movieplayer becomes fullscreen.

Why this happens..any idea ?
Help me to overcome this..thanks in advance

Here are the code for adding button on MPMovieplayer,and the screen shots

```
UIButton *skipButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
skipButton.frame = CGRectMake(264.0,195.0, 67.0, 25.0);
[skipButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
skipButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[skipButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *buttonImageNormal3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"skipad.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal3 = [buttonImageNormal3 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[skipButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImagePressed3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"skipad.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed3 = [buttonImagePressed3 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[skipButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed3 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[skipButton addTarget:self action:@selector(skipAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:skipButton];
```

**in iOS5 -**

[image: iOS5 - before fullscreen]

[image: iOS5 - after fullscreen]

**in iOS6 -**

[image: iOS6 - before fullscreen]

[image: iOS6 - after fullscreen]

Comment: Why don't you add the button to movie player's [view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/view) instead of main window?

Comment: can you specify how to add like that ??

Comment: with somethig like: [self.view addSubview:skipButton]; i guess :)

Comment: @LucaMachettelodicoaffBrognar I have tried that..but no luck

Comment: in the MoviePlayer example in xcode documentation there's overlay effects, if you haven't done yet try to looking for addOverlayView method in MyMovieViewcontroller... sound like something usefull for you :)

Comment: @LucaMachettelodicoaffBrognar..But I couldn't find anything about overlay in their documentation

Comment: `[moviePlayer.view addSubview:skipButton];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bringSubviewToFront should work, just make sure you're using it correctly. The usage is:

```
[skipButton.superview bringSubviewToFront:skipButton];
```

If that doesn't work you can change the zPosition like so:

```
skipButton.layer.zPosition = 1024.0;
```